# How to multi-provision in kitchen.yml?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have a Vagrantfile in which I am provisioning different Vm's by looping through a json file. eg.

```
cluster_config.each do |cluster|
cluster_name   = cluster[0] # name of node
nodes_config = (JSON.parse(File.read("test_data_bags/myapp/_default.json")))['clusters'][cluster_name]['nodes']

nodes_config.each do |node|


  config.vm.define node_name do |nodeconfig|  
       processes = node_values['processes']
       processes.each do |process|
          nodeconfig.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
              chef.data_bags_path = 'test_data_bags'
              chef.run_list = run_list              
              chef.roles_path = "roles"
                "myapp" => {
                  "cluster_name" => cluster_name,
                  "role" => node_role
                },
              }
          end
       end
    end
end
```

I would like to do the same within kitchen ie. take an array of attributes and foreach array item - run recipe xyz - this is so I can write some tests using test-kitchen , is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few different workarounds to accomplish this, but they are all definitely workarounds. There is an issue that was opened to discuss [support of multiple boxes on test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/184), and you can go there to read more about why this probably won't be supported any time soon. TL;DR: it's not really a goal of the project.

Workarounds include:

1. [Chef-provisioning](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning) can bootstrap more servers from a single provisioned server/test-suite
2. [Kitchen-nodes provisioner](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/multi-node-test-kitchen-tests-and-working-with-vagrant-nat-addressing-with-virtualbox) can share data about each server to the other test-suites in your setup
3. A [custom Vagrantfile template](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/master/templates/Vagrantfile.erb) for test-kitchen